# JavaScript & CSS Draggable box resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm playing around with some JavaScript draggable objects. I'm struggling to resize each box with a hashtag in `<li>` If I use `<ul id="#b0x1"><li>b0x1</ul>` I successfully resize each box but they don't work in synchrony anymore. Any suggestions on how to resolve this problem?

```js
  $( function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
  } );
```

```css
#sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 120%; height: 100% }
#sortable li { margin: 10px 10px 10px 0; padding: 1px; float: left; width: 300px; height: 290px; font-size:1em; text-align: center; }
#box1 li { margin: 10px 10px 10px 0; padding: 1px; float: left; width: 300px; height: 290px; font-size:1em; text-align: center; }
#box2 li { margin: 10px 10px 10px 0; padding: 1px; float: left; width: 300px; height: 290px; font-size:1em; text-align: center; }
#box3 li { margin: 10px 10px 10px 0; padding: 1px; float: left; width: 300px; height: 290px; font-size:1em; text-align: center; }
#box4 li { margin: 10px 10px 10px 0; padding: 1px; float: left; width: 300px; height: 290px; font-size:1em; text-align: center; }
#box5 li { margin: 10px 10px 10px 0; padding: 1px; float: left; width: 300px; height: 290px; font-size:1em; text-align: center; }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  
<ul id="sortable">
<li id="box1" class="ui-state-default">b0x1</li>
<li id="box1" class="ui-state-default">b0x2</li>
<li id="box1" class="ui-state-default">b0x3</li>
<li id="box1" class="ui-state-default">b0x4</li>
<li id="box1" class="ui-state-default">b0x5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

While you are using `jquery-ui` you could use `Resizable` to resize all boxes as you like, check below:

```js
$( function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
    $( "#sortable li" ).resizable();
  } );
```

```css
#sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 120%; height: 100% }
#sortable li { margin: 10px 10px 10px 0; padding: 1px; float: left; width: 300px; height: 290px; font-size:1em; text-align: center; }
#box1 li { margin: 10px 10px 10px 0; padding: 1px; float: left; width: 300px; height: 290px; font-size:1em; text-align: center; }
#box2 li { margin: 10px 10px 10px 0; padding: 1px; float: left; width: 300px; height: 290px; font-size:1em; text-align: center; }
#box3 li { margin: 10px 10px 10px 0; padding: 1px; float: left; width: 300px; height: 290px; font-size:1em; text-align: center; }
#box4 li { margin: 10px 10px 10px 0; padding: 1px; float: left; width: 300px; height: 290px; font-size:1em; text-align: center; }
#box5 li { margin: 10px 10px 10px 0; padding: 1px; float: left; width: 300px; height: 290px; font-size:1em; text-align: center; }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  
<ul id="sortable">
<li id="b0x1" class="ui-state-default">b0x1</li>
<li id="box1" class="ui-state-default">b0x2</li>
<li id="box1" class="ui-state-default">b0x3</li>
<li id="box1" class="ui-state-default">b0x4</li>
<li id="box1" class="ui-state-default">b0x5</li>
</ul>
```

**EDIT: It seems that the PO doesn't want to make the boxes dynamically resizable**

When you put `#box1 li` that means you want to style the `li` inside a container that holds the id of `#box1` which is wrong in your case, so instead you have to put `li#box1` (this means you want to style the `li` that holds the id `box1`)

```js
$( function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
  } );
```

```css
#sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 120%; height: 100% }
#sortable li { margin: 10px 10px 10px 0; padding: 1px; float: left; width: 300px; height: 290px; font-size:1em; text-align: center; }
li#box1 { margin: 10px 10px 10px 0; padding: 1px; float: left; width: 100px; height: 90px; font-size:1em; text-align: center; }
li#box2 { margin: 10px 10px 10px 0; padding: 1px; float: left; width: 300px; height: 290px; font-size:1em; text-align: center; }
li#box3 { margin: 10px 10px 10px 0; padding: 1px; float: left; width: 300px; height: 290px; font-size:1em; text-align: center; }
li#box4 { margin: 10px 10px 10px 0; padding: 1px; float: left; width: 300px; height: 290px; font-size:1em; text-align: center; }
li#box5 { margin: 10px 10px 10px 0; padding: 1px; float: left; width: 300px; height: 290px; font-size:1em; text-align: center; }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  
<ul id="sortable">
<li id="b0x1" class="ui-state-default">b0x1</li>
<li id="box1" class="ui-state-default">b0x2</li>
<li id="box1" class="ui-state-default">b0x3</li>
<li id="box1" class="ui-state-default">b0x4</li>
<li id="box1" class="ui-state-default">b0x5</li>
</ul>
```

Take a look at [Resizable Documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/).

Comment: A great example, but this gives the user option to resize the boxes, my idea is to predefine the sizes for each box.

Comment: @InnaIvanova do you mean that you want to hardcode the `width` and `height` on CSS but you can't figure out why they are not applied?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: there was a misunderstanding due to your question format